# Owin Call Duration

Tags: c#, owin, middleware

Is there simple way to find the call duration in c#.

I am using Owin middleware to intercept calls to an API and log information about them and part of what I would like to log is the duration of the call.

```
public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
{
   var request = context.Request;
   var response = context.Response;
   var userName = request.User != null && request.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? request.User.Identity.Name : "No username";

   var entity = new TrackingEntity()
   {
      UserName = userName
   };

   // invoke the next middleware in the pipeline

   await Next.Invoke(context);

   WriteRequestHeaders(request, entity);
   WriteResponseHeaders(response, entity);

   await storage.InsertEntity(entity);
}
```

If my tracking entity has a Duration field on it for storing the time length of the call what is the best way to go about recording it?

```
public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
```

Is the most accurate way to use a timer that starts before calling next and ends after?

Any input would be appreciated I think I'm just overthinking this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: write a filter and use stopwatch to compute the time spent... use reflection to check if property exist in response and set it accordingly

Comment: @entre Sorry I'm relatively new to Owin. Create an owin filter? Or an Asp.net action filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that you need the overhead of creating a timer, just record the start time into a variable and then end time in another variable to set the duration.

```
var startTime = DateTime.Now;
await Next.Invoke(context);
var endTime = DateTime.Now;
Duration = endTime - startTime;
```

It's a little messy, but if all you are doing in this middleware is logging, you want it to be quick, and this should fit the bill.